# Can not install ros package via $svn co http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see some wiki page recommend to get ros package via  command like this

$svn co http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/octomap_mapping-experimental/

but when I use it in terminal,it tells me

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/freiburg_tools/gaussian_process'
svn: E160013: can not find the path “/svn/trunk/freiburg_tools/gaussian_process”
```

And I also can not open this website http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com ?
Is something wrong with my Internet or this website?

My ros environment:
Ubuntu 16.04  Ros kinetic

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284751/can-not-install-ros-package-via-$svn-co-http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/.../) by [Summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/33945/summer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-07**:
What tutorial are you referring to? It's helpful to include all relevant information.

**Comment by [Summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/33945/summer/) on 2018-03-08**:
http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam_electric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Google Code shutdown in 2015](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html) so it's no surprise that you can't access it. According to that article, Google migrated much of their code to [GitHub](http://github.com/google) and created a tool for developers to move their code as well. However,as far as I know, Google didn't migrate other's code on its own.

---

**Edit:**

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=alufr+ros) led me to the [`alufr-ros-pkg` archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/alufr-ros-pkg/). They too moved to GitHub though:

- OCTOMAP-related ROS stacks have moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/OctoMap)
- NAO-related stacks have moved to GitHub: [`nao_robot` repo](https://github.com/ahornung/nao_robot) and [`nao_common` repo](https://github.com/ahornung/nao_common)

---

**Edit 2:**

Here's a [GitHub clone](https://github.com/svn2github/gaussian_process) of the `freiburg_tools/gaussian_process` package that you were trying to clone.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2